# Firebase MLKit text recognition fail with the front camera iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have integrated the `Firebase MLKit  SDK` as per the document, texts are detected correctly with the `back camera` photo. When I am using a captured photo from the front camera, texts are detecting wrongly and bad results are coming out.

```
 @IBAction func findTextDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    runTextRecognition(with:imageView.image!)
  }

func runCloudTextRecognition(with image: UIImage) {
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    cloudTextDetector.detect(in: visionImage) { features, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("Received error: \(error)")
        return
      }
      self.processCloudResult(from: features, error: error)
    }
  }


  for text in features {
      if let block = text as? VisionTextBlock {
        print(block.text)
      }
    }
```

I am not able to figure out. Do I need change with the camera or firebase ml kit?

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did, It is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide image orientation as well. Adding code snippet may help you.

```
let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)

   let metadata = VisionImageMetadata()
        metadata.orientation = self.detectorOrientation(in: image)
        visionImage.metadata = metadata
 textDetector.process(visionImage) { (features, error) in
            if features != nil
            {
                self.processResult(from: [features!], error: error)
            }
        }
//Detects orientation of the selected or captured image
    func detectorOrientation(in image: UIImage) -> VisionDetectorImageOrientation {
        switch image.imageOrientation {
        case .up:
            return .topLeft
        case .down:
            return .bottomRight
        case .left:
            return .leftBottom
        case .right:
            return .rightTop
        case .upMirrored:
            return .topRight
        case .downMirrored:
            return .bottomLeft
        case .leftMirrored:
            return .leftTop
        case .rightMirrored:
            return .rightBottom
        }
    }
```